# Filtering for all LDAP-values with the same "name" in a specific folder?

Tags: ldap, filtering

first of all: I am not very familiar with the LDAP. 
I was able to perform some easy searches with basic filtering using VBS, but now I am at a point, where I am stuck.

The directory-structure looks like that

```
BASE
-> O=Company
---> OU=peopleInGroups
-------> CN=DbAdministrator
```

in the folder CN=DbAdministrator I have lots of entries like

```
uniquemember = CN=Simon Sample, OU = people, O = Company
uniquemember = CN=Sally Sample, OU = people, O = Company
uniquemember = ...
```

where uniquemeber is the name of the field and 'CN=Simon Sample, OU = people, O = Company' is the value.

Does anybody know, how I can get all those DbAdministrators with one filter?
If not, what would be the way to do it?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The filter URL is

```
ldap://hostname/cn=dbAdministrator,ou=peopleInGroups,o=Company?uniqueMember?one
```

But you don't need a filter. Just look up the dbAdministrator object and get its uniqueMember attribute values.